# $\operatorname{dim}_xX=\operatorname{sup}_{Z\in I}\operatorname{dim}Z$ for a $k$-scheme locally of finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is Prop. 5.26 of Görtz/Wedhorn. We have a field $k$ and a scheme $X$ that is locally of finite type over $k$, as well as a point $x\in X$ and the set $I$ of all irreducible components of $X$ containing $x$. Then the claim is that $\operatorname{dim}_xX=\operatorname{sup}_{Z\in I}\operatorname{dim}Z$.

The proof starts with the sentence "As the set of irreducible components of $X$ is locally finite, $\operatorname{dim}_xX=\operatorname{inf}_U\operatorname{dim}U$ where $U$ runs trough those open neighbourhoods of $x$ which meet precisely the irreducible components in $I$."

This I don't really get at the moment. I think we may assume that $X=\operatorname{Spec} A$ with a finitely generated $k$-algebra $A$, and then the irreducible components in $I$ correspond to the minimal prime ideals $\mathfrak{q}_1,\ldots,\mathfrak{q}_n$ of $A$ contained in $\mathfrak{p}_x$. Do I have to show that every principal open $D(s)$ that meets all $Z\in I$ automatically contains $\mathfrak{p}_x$? Or what do the authors mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Since the set of all irreducible components of $X$ is locally finite, every neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ intersects atmost finitely many of them, say $Z_1,\dots, Z_n$.

WLOG assume that $Z_1,\dots, Z_r\in I$ (i.e. $x\in Z_i$) and $Z_{r+1},\dots, Z_n\notin I$.

Consider $V:=U-(Z_{r+1}\cup \cdots\cup Z_n)$.    Now $x\in V$ and $V$ intersects $I$.

This shows the claim that it is enough to take 'inf' over neighbourhoods meeting $I$.

Comment: @Thanks. Could you accept the answer if you are fully satisfied with it?